# How to enable WordPress to have multiple sites without a re-direct

Tags: redirect, wordpress, 301-redirect

I'm using WordPress to manage my site and when the site does a re-direct, it slows down performance.

For example, WordPress allows you a single default site, www.mycompany.com.  If a user goes to mycompany.com, WP will re-direct it www.mycompany.com.  Is there a way to configure WP so that it will listen on both www.mycompany.com and mycompany.com without redirects.  The redirects are causing performance hits to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a .htaccess on the root directory and if inside it you have something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or something similar.